# Rename a category in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I programmatically rename a category in WordPress? I can't find any method for it in the Codex.

Obviously I'd like all posts in that category to be updated to be in the newly named category.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something like this before

There is a function in wordpress for it.

Example

```
 /* category name change*/
wp_update_term( 2, 'category', array(
    'name' => 'Repeated',
) );
```

Here i change the specific category name

There are three parameter:-
1. term id of category taxonomy
2. taxonomy name ( i.e. category )
3. arguments ( here I changed the name only, you can change the slug and etc. )